# Ajax error on server using domain name, working fine on local machine using localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

Getting the following error during ajax call:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://www.example.com/Ad/Filter"
```

However working fine on local machine using localhost

### Code Snippet :

"Category" contains list of string values

```
function filter(Category) {
 var Categories = Category;
 $.ajax({
    url: "/Ad/Filter",
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    data: { categories: Categories },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#finalResult').html(data);
        },
    error: function (response) {
        var r = (response.responseText);
        alert("Message: " + r.Message);
        alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
        alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
    }
 });
}
```

All error values are undefined, unable to trace the error.

Comment: I could see 404 in that URL!

Comment: Can you inspect the server error? There is an exception that isn't getting caught.

Comment: Either add logging to your action method or use something like ELMAH to automatically log errors. There's a stack trace somewhere, and we're not going to be able to help you without it.

Comment: I tried logging this JS error using ELMAH, JSLogger and BugSnag nothing helped, Unable to trace the exact error.